# operator>> works in Visual C++ 2010 but not G++ on Linux

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following problem:

I have code that works fine with visual c++ 2010,
but when I compile it on Linux, it get compiled, but something there doesn't work:

this is my `Vector` input `operator>>` :

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in,Vector& x)
{
char a;
in.sync();
a=in.get(); //gets the '['
for(int i=0;i<x._n;i++)
    {
        in>>x._vector[i];
        if ((i+1)!=x._n)
        a=in.get(); //gets the ','
    }
in>>a; //gets the ']'
return in;
}
```

`_vector` points on an array of `Complex` number,
the `operator>>` of the `Complex` works fine.

The input is supposed to look like this:

```
[2+3i,9i,1]
```

When I run this code on visual c++ 2010, it works, and looks like this:

```
cin>>v; // [1+1i,2]
cin>>u; // [10,5i]
cout<<v<<endl; //prints: [1+i,2]
cout<<u<<endl; //prints: [10,5i]
```

When I run the same code on Linux, after the first array `[1+1i,2]` the program ends:

```
[1+1i,2]  //this is the input
[6.105e-317+6.105e-317i,6.105e-317+6.105e-317i]
[6.105e-317+6.105e-317i,6.105e-317+6.105e-317i]
```

Now I can't even write the other `Vector`

btw:
this is my Vector.h

```
#ifndef _VECTOR_
#define _VECTOR_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Complex.h"

class Vector
{
private:
    int _n;
    Complex *_vector; //points on the array of the complex numbers
public:
    Vector(int n); // "Vector" - constructor of Vector with n instants
    Vector(const Vector& x);  // "Vector" - copy constructor of Vector with n instants
~Vector(); // "~Vector" - destructor of Vector
const Vector& operator=(const Vector& x); // "operator=" - operates "=" for Vector
Complex& operator[](const int index); // "operator[]" - choose an instant by his index in the _vector
const Vector operator+(const Vector& x) const; // "operator+" - operates "+" between two vectors
const Vector operator-(const Vector& x) const; // "operator-" - operates "-" between two vectors
const Vector operator*(double scalar) const; // "operator*" - multiplate all of the instants of the vector by the scalar
friend const Vector operator*(double scalar,const Vector& x); // "operator*" - multiplate all of the instants of the vector by the scalar
const Complex operator*(const Vector& x) const; // "operator*" - operates "*" between two vectors
const Vector& operator+=(const Vector& x); // "operator+=" - operates "+=" for the instant
const Vector& operator-=(const Vector& x); // "operator-=" - operates "-=" for the instant
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Vector& x); // "operator<<" - prints the vector
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in,Vector& x); // "operator<<" - gets the vector
const double operator!() const; // "operator!" - returns the the instant in the definite value of the vactor that his definite value is the highest (in the Vector)
};
    #endif
```

and here is where i define the constructor of Vector:
Vector.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include <math.h>
#include "Complex.h"
#include "Vector.h"

// "Vector" - constructor of Vector with n instants
Vector::Vector(int n)
{
    _vector=new Complex[n]; //new vector (array) of complex classes
    _n=n;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you include how you defined / declared your `Vector` objects? How did you initialize `_n`?

Comment: You could probably get some very useful information if you did error checking -- e.g. test to make sure the stream hasn't failed every time you read something, and check that you actually got `[` when you think you're reading it.

Comment: i did this error checking, it works fine on visual c++ 2010, but it fails on linux... and there i can't do this error checking

Comment: Is it something to do with line termination ending in `\r\n` on Windows and `\n` on linux?

Comment: We need a short compilable example. btw, you used `_n` in the loop of `operator >>`, are your sure the number of complex numbers in the file is the same as `_n`?

Comment: the size of the vector is "_n", so this loop go'es _n times, so i enter _n Complex classes (i use operator>> like scanf, i'm not reading from a file)

the error is that i enter the first vector, press enter, and then it does'nt let me to enter the second vector

Comment: [1+1i,2]  //this is the input of the first vector
not it skeeps on getting the second vector, and prints garbage
[6.105e-317+6.105e-317i,6.105e-317+6.105e-317i]
[6.105e-317+6.105e-317i,6.105e-317+6.105e-317i]

Comment: i gave an example in the message, look for this:
"When I run this code on visual c++ 2010, it works, and looks like this:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the problem is in your call to `in.sync()`.

This flushes the input buffer, i.e. it discards whatever data is currently in the istream's buffer. What exactly gets put into the buffer depends on a) your platform and b) what you did before you call `operator>>`.

As for b), this is why it's wrong to call `sync` from an `operator>>`, but that's "your problem".

As for a), you should know that UNIX systems do line buffering for console text input at the operating system level, before istream gets a say. Data that you want to flush might be in the operating system buffer instead of in istream's buffer.

If you just want to skip whitespace, you should use `in >> std::ws;`